# How to use CAP_SYS_ADMIN

Tags: c, linux-capabilities

Can somebody please explain to me how to use or set CAP_SYS_ADMIN in c?
I need that capability to unmount a usb drive but don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 22):

Here's how to do it using the command-line:

```
$  sudo setcap cap_sys_admin+ep executable-name
```

and

```
$ getcap executable-name
executable-name = cap_sys_admin+ep
```

You, of course, need the [libcap](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/) package.

A good place to learn how to do it in C would be the source for `setcap` which is [here](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/morgan/libcap.git/tree/progs/setcap.c)

Comment: How do I set it back? If I do **$ getcap /usr/bin/ffmpeg** I get empty return. So how do I remove that capability?

Comment: @HarryH an empty return means capabilities aren't set on the file so there is nothing to remove. The `+ep` in the example sets it and you would use `-ep` to remove it. The meaning of the flags are "effective" and "permitted" and you can read more on `man 7 capabilities`. The syntax of the commands is described by `man 3 cap_from_text`.