# Copying Text File to USB Stick

Tags: c++, qt, operating-system

When I copy text file to USB Flash Memory with this line in Raspberry Pi 3;

```
if (QFile::copy(LastDayWaitListSource, LastDayWaitListTarget)) {
    qDebug() << "Copy OK";
}
```

Copy OK was appeared in the debug screen.

Then remove USB Flash memory from Raspberry Pi , and plug in to the Windows 10 Laptop to see the text file.There is no text file in USB flash memory.

Then I repeat same process with one different process.

After copying the text file,  I opened the USB flash memory directory in Linux `/media/pi/USB_Stick_Dir` to see the copied text file. And I saw copied text file.Then I removed USB Flash memory from Raspberry Pi , and plug in to the Windows 10 Laptop and this time I saw the copied text file in Windows also.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried looking for hidden files in first try?

Comment: Yes , i tried now.Same.

Comment: It's also can caused by permission problems, Try opening file explorer as administrator in your windows system.

Comment: Any luck with permissions?

Comment: No,unfortunately

Comment: My last guess is that you are not unmount your USB flash properly from source system before removing it. Try `sudo umount /media/pi/USB_Stick_Dir` and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Yes,this time worked.Thank you.

Comment: But i can't do this directly because i will use QT application as a fullscreen HMI panel.

Comment: Have a look at **EDIT** on my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not unmounting your USB drive before removing it from your Linux system. try:

```
sudo umount /media/pi/USB_Stick_Dir
```

**EDIT :**
You can do this inside your Qt program too, to do this you need to have [CAP_SYS_ADMIN](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) privilege.

The CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability allows a process to perform various administrative tasks, like calling `mount()`and `umount()`. You can do something like this to unmount your drive within your program :

```
int res = umount("/media/pi/USB_Stick_Dir")
if (!res) {
    qDebug() << "Device unmounted successfuly";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion i think it will work.How can i have CAP_SYS_ADMIN privilage?

Comment: You are welcome, checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504457/how-to-use-cap-sys-admin) to learn how to have `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`.

Comment: i examined this link.What is 'ep executable-name'

Comment: It's not `ep executable-name`. it's `cap_sys_admin+ep` and `executable-name`. Here `executable-name` refers to your application (binary) name, The file that you execute for your application to run.

Comment: i exactly write this ; sudo setcap cap_sys_admin+ep /appFilepath/app.run .But didn't work

Comment: hmm... write what?

Comment: i wrote application path+application name after cap_sys_admin+ep

Comment: What didn't work? the command or `umount` function? did you get `libcap` package?

Comment: i just downloaded libcap package .What will i do with this ?

Comment: You need to install the package, if you don't know how to do that you can either learn how to install package on you Linux machine or ask another question to get help for that, the rule is `one question per topic`.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for your answers.

Comment: By the i opened new title.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175017/how-to-install-package-on-linux